# Destroy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller which has no show action.

The current destroy looks like this:

```
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', subscriber, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

I do not want it to point to {subscriber}, as that route does not exist.  Instead I want it to direct to the subscribers index

```
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', subscribers_path, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

However when I do this I get the following error:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/subscribers"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

These are my routes:

```
   resources :subscribers
  match 'subscribe' => 'Subscribers#subscribe'
  match 'unsubscribe' => 'Subscribers#unsubscribe'
```

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: rake routes to check the route ;)

Comment: ah ok,  I see.  delete is not the same as destroy even though it calls the same url?  I need to just leave it as it is by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say that route doesn't exist, I assume you aren't using resource routing. That means you probably have something like

```
match 'subscribers' => 'subscribers#index', :via => :get
get 'subscribers' => 'subscribers#index'
```

None of these will actually match a delete request, which you can verify by running `rake routes` from the app root.

You could adjust it like the following, to make it match:

```
match 'subscribers' => 'subscribers#index', :via => [ :get , :delete ]
```

Also, this might make more sense with more information, but it seems like the deviation from a more traditional REST-based approach may cause an unnecessary and possibly confusing lack of clarity while maintaining the application.